# Brain tree payment transaction

Tags: braintree

The credit card verification,customer id,payment method token details are maintained in one merchant account that is 'A', I need payment transaction synchronized with another brain tree merchant account 'B' using credentials provided to merchant account 'A'.

If it's possible?

Comment: I work at Braintree. It doesn't sound like something you can do yourself; everything is separated by merchant. If you [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) they'll be able to help you out.

Comment: I try to transaction with sub merchant account id but throw the "invalid keys: serviceFeeAmount" error message.

see PHP code for transaction: 


$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
  'merchantAccountId' => '3pnsgqsv8hktd2b2',
  'amount' => '300.00',
  'creditCard' => array(
    'number' => '5105105105105100',
    'expirationDate' => '05/12'
  ),
  'serviceFeeAmount' => "10.00"
));

Answer (score 0):

Try passing your submerchant account id instead of merchant account id.
MerchantAccountId = "submerchant account id",
for more details please visit [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/dotnet)